# using curl and json to return a token

Tags: php, json, curl

Site A has all my php classes and functions:

Here's what's in my action (profile.php) page SITEA:

```
$shopper = new Shopper($email);
$shopper->login($password);

$cInit = curl_init("http://siteA/test/login");
curl_setopt_array($cInit, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>urlencode(implode("&", array("email" => $email, "password" => $password)))
    ));

    $content = curl_exec($cInit);
    $err     = curl_errno($cInit);
    $errmsg  = curl_error($cInit);

    $results = json_decode($content)
?>
```

Site B is hosted on a different server it has the form and curl options:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$shopper = new Shopper();
$token = $shopper->login($email, $password);

echo json_encode(array("token" => $token)); 

<form id='register' action='http://siteA/test/profile' onsubmit="return validateForm()" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Log In</legend><br/>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50" /><br/><br/>
    <label for="password">Password*:</label>  
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

The token keeps returning false, does my code look correct up to this point?

Comment: I guess the real question is ... inside the `$cInit = curl_init("");`... is this suppose to go back to the login page?

Comment: site a has `$shopper = new Shopper($email);`,  but B has `$shopper = new Shopper();`. Is the parameter a difference in the problem?

Comment: `curl_init("")` set's the curl opt `CURLOPT_URL` | which is to say, this is the url it goes after or fetches

Comment: So does the url have to point back to the login page?

Comment: It needs to point at where you're posting info too. So if your login also contains the post functions (not a great practice) then yes. But if your expecting run your `POST` variables through other functions on another page then no. In your case you're posting `email` and `passowrd`, which means whatever page u "curl" too you're expecting to have `$_POST['email']`

Comment: What would be a better practice than having my post variables there like above?

Comment: By not best practice, I was meaning keeping your post functions on same page. I would put them in a file for dealing with post functions. Then post to that url, and have your post login function handle redirect as necessary.

Comment: I still can't figure out why i'm getting `{"token":false}`

Answer (score 0):

### NOT AN ANSWER | POSSIBLY HELPFUL IN EVALUATING PROBLEM

---

I'm not sure yet, just seeing what i've seen and conversing with you, but perhaps this can help you evaluate.  The following code snippet will make it easier for you to evaluate what's going on to some extent. The use is as simple as a `var_dump`, but the results are much easier to read in a browser as it simply takes your dump and places some nice HTML around it. It also accepts as many parameters as you feed it, thus making it easy to evaluate multiple variables at a time.

```
function preDump() {    //  use string "noEcho" to just get a string return only
    $args = func_get_args();
    $doEcho = TRUE; $sb;
    if ($args) {
        $sb = '<div style="margin: 1em 0;"><fieldset style="display:inline-block;padding:0em 3em 1em 1em;"><legend><b>preDump: '.count($args).' Parameters Found.</b></legend>';
        foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
            if (gettype($arg) == 'string') if ($arg == 'noEcho') { $doEcho = FALSE; $sb = preg_replace('/(preDump: )[0-9]+/', 'preDump: '.(count($args)-1), $sb); continue; }
            $sb .= '<pre data-type="'.gettype($arg).'"';
            switch (gettype($arg)) {
                case "boolean":
                case "integer":
                    $sb .= ' data-dump="json_encode"><p style="border-bottom:1px solid;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 1em;"><b>gettype('.gettype($arg).')</b></p><p>';
                    $sb .= json_encode($arg);
                    break;
                case "string":
                    $sb .= ' data-dump="echo"><p style="border-bottom:1px solid;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 1em;"><b>gettype('.gettype($arg).')</b></p><p>';
                    $sb .= $arg;
                    break;
                default:
                    $sb .= ' data-dump="var_dump"';
                    if (is_object($arg)) $sb .= 'data-class="'.get_class($arg).'"';
                    $sb .= '><p style="border-bottom:1px solid;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 1em;"><b>gettype('.gettype($arg).')';
                    if (is_object($arg)) $sb .= ' ['.get_class($arg).']';
                    $sb .= '</b></p><p>';
                    ob_start();
                    var_dump($arg);
                    $sb .= ob_get_clean();
                    if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_clean();
            }
            $sb .= '</p></pre>';
        }
        $sb .= '</fieldset></div>';
    }
    else {
        $sb = '<div style="margin: 1em 0;"><fieldset style="display:inline-block;"><legend><b>preDump: [ERROR]</b></legend><h3>No Parameters Found</h3></fieldset></div>';
    }
    if ($doEcho) echo($sb);
    return $sb;
}
```

I suggest this, because I feel like there is a little more code here we're missing and your operating 2 differences on 2 different servers. Thus you might make use of this as follows:

### Site A

```
function preDump() { ... }

$shopper = new Shopper($email);
$shopper->login($password);

//  Maybe go ahead and test your results of shopper here
preDump($shopper); return;

$cInit = curl_init("http://siteA/test/login");
curl_setopt_array(
    $cInit,
    array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>urlencode(implode("&", array("email" => $email, "password" => $password)))
    )
);

$content = curl_exec($cInit);
$err     = curl_errno($cInit);
$errmsg  = curl_error($cInit);

$results = json_decode($content)
//  or, remove that line i put up above and test your results here
preDump($results); return;

//  you can even get the preDump results as a string and then echo as you see fit
$bob = preDump($results, 'noEcho'); //  string of 'noEcho' will cause the results to return as a string not be echoed into browser
```